# Change all materials of renderer to one material

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have multiple mesh renderers, most of them have more than 2 or 3 materials. I want all the mesh renderers' materials to be switched to one material and then re-switch to its old materials. How do I do this?

```
public MeshRenderer[] renderer;
public Material switchMat;

private void Start () {
        for (int i = 0; i < renderer.Length; i++) {
            renderer[i].materials[i] = switchMat; //Switch to new Material - not working
        }
    }

private void SwitchBack(){
      for (int i = 0; i < renderer.Length; i++) {
            //Switch back to original Material
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you are only switching exactly one material per renderer by both times using `i` as the index. You will need to have **two** loops, one for iterating through all renderers, the other one for going through all materials of current renderer!

And then you could probably just store the original materials in a `Dictionary` like

```
private Dictionary<Renderer, Material[]> _originalMaterials = new Dictionary<Renderer, Material[]>();

private void Start () 
{
    // Iterate through all renderers
    foreach (var rend in renderer) 
    {
        // store a copy of the array linked to this renderer
        _originalMaterials.Add(rend, rend.materials);

        // get the current (original) materials instances
        // Renderer.materials returns a new copy of the array every time
        var materials = rend.materials;

        // in the local array simply replace all elements
        for(var i = 0; i < materials.Length; i++){
            materials[i] = switchMat;
        }

        // assign back the entire materials array
        rend.materials = materials;
    }
}

private void SwitchBack()
{
    // Iterate through all renderers
    foreach (var rend in renderer) 
    {
        // Check if for current renderer there is an entry in the dictionary
        if(_originalMaterials.TryGetValue(rend, out var materials))
        {
            // if so assign back the entire original array
            rend.materials = materials;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately not all materials are getting assigned back to renderer. Just the first one gets assigned back inside the SwitchBack() function.

Comment: I am having 3 renderers and 6 materials. The 2 renderers have 3 and 2 materials respectively. In SwitchBack() function, only the first renderer gets its original material back. But the rest remain the same. The if statement ```f(_originalMaterials.TryGetValue(rend, out var materials))``` gets called only once.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint in the `SwitchBack` method, how many entries does `_originalMaterials` have and how many elements are in `renderer` during `Start` and during `SwitchBack` ?

Comment: Yes i tried that. I added a log before ```if(_originalMaterials.TryGetValue(rend, out var materials))``` and the log prints 6 times because of 6 materials. and then I added log inside the if statement and it prints only once, since the material is assigned only to first renderer.

Comment: `and the log prints 6 times because of 6 materials` .. no this wouldn't happen ... it should print once per **renderer** not material.

Comment: My bad there are 6 renderers. The log gets printed 6 times because of that. And there are 8 materials in total but only the first rend is assigned to its original material.

Comment: So the `_originalMaterials` only has 1 entry?

Comment: Yes I am afraid it gets called only once. Why though?

Comment: There is no problem in assigning the renderers to new material in the start, that works well.

Comment: By gets called you mean the `TryGetValue` returns `true` only once .. how often is `_originalMaterials.Add(...)` executed?

Comment: Ah ```_originalMaterials.Add(...)``` gets executed only once. That is really weird.

Comment: I found my mistake. I had accidentally added a bool inside the foreach() for another purpose and which is why it was getting called only once. I am sorry for taking so much of your time. It was completely my ignorance.